# Computing k-means

Tags: r, algorithm, math, data-mining, k-means

How can I compute the standard k-means (Euclidean distance measure) with R?
As an example the following data points are given `{-3, -2, -1, 0, 2, 4,}`. Using `k=2` and starting with cluster seeds `c1 = −1, c2 = 0`.

This is what I got so far:

```
data <- c(-3,-2,-1,0,2,4)
kmeans(data, method="euclidean")
```

Comment: did you read the `kmeans` documentation? `help(kmeans)`... `method` isn't an argument for my `kmeans`... to pass the starting `centers` use the `centers` argument... `kmeans(data, centers=c(-1, 0))`

Comment: looking at `?kmeans`, `method` is not an option of `kmeans`. However, `algorithm` is. Looking at `?kmeans` again, I see that `Lloyd` is one of the possible algorithms. According to Wikipedia, the standard k-means with Euclidean distance measure is also referred to as "Lloyd's algorithm".

Comment: @Justin: Thank you, but it says `Error: empty cluster: try a better set of initial centers`.

Comment: Not for me on R version 3.0.2... please include the output of `sessionInfo()` in your question.

Comment: R version 3.0.1 (2013-05-16)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
[...]
loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] tools_3.0.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you set the clusters with the centers parameter so it would resemble:

```
kmeans(data, centers = c(-1,0))
```